# Is there any date picker for Java Swing when I click the textfield and it pops up?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

Is there any date picker for Java Swing when I click the textfield and the calendar pops up and I can choose the date?? (without any extra button please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: 2019**

Under active development, you'll find [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker)

These features are included: DatePicker, TimePicker, DateTimePicker, CalendarPanel

**Update: 2017**

When this question was asked, the SwingX project still existed and JXDatePicker control was one option to use.

Currently I can no longer find any trace of this project and to be honest I don't even know if swing still exists :). I'm marking this answer as community wiki, so if anyone knows anything about this subject he/she can update it freely.

**Old answer:**

Swingx has a nice JXDatePicker control. Since Oracle moved java.net to kenai it's a bit of an adventure to find anything.

Here is the main page:
http://swingx.java.net/

There a JWS demo there too.

and here's the download area

http://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/1.6.2/

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no date picker component in Java swing. You can try [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html) - date chooser.

Comment: i know JCalendar but i need from the text field that automatically pops up.. i dont want any extra button near it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) (since there no popup window) for implemented `SpinnerDateModel`