# Date Picker GUI component for Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, date, user-interface, netbeans

I am sure this question has been  asked before, but I could not find the answer. I am seeking for a `Date Picker` GUI component which I can drag and drop from `Netbeans` IDE. I found the below.

1. http://toedter.com/software/ - This is not free for commercial use.
2. http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/658/jdatechooser-1-2 - This has issues, the dates are invisible.

So anyone know whether there is a free for commercial use `Date Picker` component for Java, which we can drag and drop from Netbeans?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any date picker for Java Swing when I click the textfield and it pops up?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8589485/3755692)

Comment: @msrd0: Did you miss my "Free for Commercial Use" part?

Comment: @Sniper I thought the accepted answer points to `JCalendar`, which is part of Swing ...

Comment: @msrd0: `JCalender` is not a part of Swing. It is a custom component. Not free for commercial use.

Comment: @Sniper And another one points that there is a model by Swing for `JSpinner`, also possible to use

Comment: Any component which extends from `JComponent` (actually `Component`) can be dragged into the form editor, find one you like, include the Jar with in your project and go nuts

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Glad to see you here. Anything "free for commercial" stuff? ANDDD.."Go Nuts" means?

Comment: Go nuts means, knock yourself, have fun, go wild, get it done.  You could look at the SwingLabs, SwingX library, pretty sure there's one in there

Comment: @MadProgrammer: This one? - https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases. Is it free for commercial use? I can see big logos there!

Comment: It's open source and we use it our project without issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Can you provide it as an answer please? And please point out it is free for commercial, lot of people will find it really helpfull.

Comment: What makes `JCalendar` not free for commercial use?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Just have a look at the site. It says `LGPL or contact me for commercial license`

Comment: I got down to the GNU license, couldn't find mention of a commerical license

Comment: JCalendar: *"License 
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation. If you like and use it, just let me know. If you find any errors or things you don’t like, please contact Kai Toedter"*...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: hmm..Any idea about how to use this on commercial product then?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Regarding the `SwingX` their one also nice, but you can't navigate through years easily.

Comment: You want to contact the author and just double check their intentions.  As for the SwingX version, you can get the source and modify it ;)

Comment: The [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/) library includes a good **DatePicker** component. (As well as the TimePicker and DateTimePicker classes). The three components are simple and easy to use. All the components can be used from the NetBeans visual designer. (And the other popular IDEs). The licence is the MIT open source license. Screenshots and a demo application are at the project home page: github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

Answer (score 6):

Netbeans will allow you to drag any component that extends from `JComponent`, so long as the class is within the project's classpath.

Once the jar file has been linked to your project, you should be able to expand the jar contents (under the libraries node) and drag the class onto the form.

I do this for my own custom components (.java files) all the time.

If this seems cumbersome, you can also add the components to the Swing component palette.

- From the Tools menu, select Palette -> Swing/AWT Components
- Create a new Category for your components
- Select "Add from Jar..."
- Select the Jar, make sure that the Jar is within a stable location AND is added to any project that wants to use the components!
- The wizard will scan the contents and present you with choices you can add, select the components that you actually want
- Select the category that you want them added to (probably the one you just added) and select "Finish"

In the palette, expand your category (make sure you selected it within the "Palette Manager") and you should all the components

[image: DatePicker]

A, general, free to use component library is the [SwingLabs, SwingX library](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases), so long as you don't try and sell it, you should be able to use freely, you also get access to the source code, so if you want to add featrues, you should also be able to.  I would suggest that if you do, you should notify them and offer what changes you can, so the community can benefit.

The `JXDatePicker` is highly customisable, but you'll need to get your hands dirty with some code to be the best features...

Comment: I did this step and added successfully but when I drag, nothing is placed on the frame. There is some change to the frame. I can say this because the file is highlighted (which means unsaved in netbeans). Could you please help

Comment: @NikithaReddy The only thing I can suggest without any kind of context is that the layout manager has been set to `null` (or `AbsoluteLayout`)

Comment: It wasn't null but I ended up with a wrong jar.. and the components were not right.. For eg. it was jDatePickerUtil instead of jDatePicker.. Can you suggest me the jar that you used.. I tried with jxdatepicker-support-1.0.jar but that didn't work for me.. Now I am using jcalendar-1.4.jar(this works)

Comment: The [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/) library includes a good **DatePicker** component. (As well as the TimePicker and DateTimePicker classes). The three components are simple and easy to use. These components can be used from the NetBeans visual designer. (And the other popular IDEs). The licence is the MIT open source license. Screenshots and a demo application are at the project home page: github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

Answer (score 4):

You can use JDatePicker. Download from this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/

it's used like other Swing components:

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);

frame.add(datePicker);
```

Comment: You can't drag and drop this in Netbeans

Comment: Use the download link from http://jdatepicker.org the binaries are being distributed via maven central repo.