# JDateChooser is not displaying any dates

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, plugins

I am using the below library `JDateChooser`, which is a Date Picker GUI which we can put into Netbeans pallet.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/658/jdatechooser-1-2

However this do not display any dates. Dates are empty. Below is the image.

[image]

I do not have to post the code here, because I did nothing other than dragging and dropping the GUI element. Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like a layout issue

Comment: You do realise that you put an component that in the palette or frag them onto the form designer directly...see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323390/date-picker-gui-component-for-java-swing/26324394#26324394) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Hi, Are you getting the same issue? I followed what they have said in their "Readme" file.

Comment: It doesn't work with Nimbus, go harass the author...In the mean time, I'd recommend the `JXDatePicker` from SwingLabs, SwingX library, see previously linked answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I do agree about the `JXDatePicker`, but I am out of time to develop it further so it can support year navigation!

Comment: Then change your look and feel

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Thanks for the point! This might be a stupid question, but must ask. If I use `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName` can it "ever" be `nimbus` in any OS?

Comment: That's a hard call, most code that "suggests" using Nimbus has you looking to see if it's available on the system.  The "long" answer is it's possible, if the system doesn't have a default system look and feel and has been configured to use it

Comment: @MadProgrammer: oh..hmm...Any other, free, royalty free, free for commercial use look and feel out there?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I think JGoddies is!

Comment: I'm not sure that the date picker is for JGoodies...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Just checked, it works with JGoodies. Please provide your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JDateChooser` from `vadimig` doesn't seem to work with Nimbus, seems to work okay for Windows look and feel, you'd have to test it with the other system looks feels.

Either change the component you are using or change the look and feel you are using

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the width of the component, just increase that value.
If your DateChooserCombo is called chooserDate, it must be like this:

```
Dimension size = chooserDate.getCalendarPreferredSize();<br>
size.width += 90;<br>
chooserDate.setCalendarPreferredSize(size);<br>
```