# How to prevent datechoosercombo to overlay the awt list?

Tags: java, swing

Whenever I open the date dialog box it overlays the previously present list. Can anyone please tell me how to prevent this?

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: [`DateChooserCombo`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26352981/230513)? Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

There are strange lags into swing forms. Try to set window listener to datechoosercombo frame, use windowClosed() method into this listener and call repaint() method of 'Record view' frame. In these cases this repaint() method should be into thread like:

```
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
{
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
       {
             @Override
             public void run()
             {
                 RecordsViewInstance.repaint();
             }
        });
 }
```