# jDateChooser not showing day number

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdatechooser

I am developing an app in Java using the jDateChooser library. I am using NetBeans as my IDE. When I include a jDateChooser combo through the components palette. I doesn't show me the number of the day. Instead it shows `...`. I attach you an image below of my problem.
[image]

I have tried to make the JFrame bigger but, it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using a null layout? Please post a [mcve] that we can copy-paste and see your issue. This seems like a layout issue, btw which Look & Feel are you using? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352981/jdatechooser-is-not-displaying-any-dates) is related

Comment: Yes, I am using a null layout and the default look and feel with NetBeans 8.1. I don't know how to customize the look and feel.

Comment: Null layout is not the best option, but if you read the Introduction of JDateChooser 1.2 plugin, you will see that there could be issues with localization: "6) Localization. Component supports all dates localizations presented in JDK. User editors and properties descriptions are localized too, but currently only for two languages: Russian and English. Javadoc both in English and Russian."  
There is a great, localization-safe, alternative, called JCalendar, by Kai Tödter you could use instead. http://toedter.com/jcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = jDateChooser1.getDate();
```

format that Date value to a String

```
String strDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
```

set that value as the text for the lable...

```
jLabel1.setText(strDate);
```